# Telegram bot - how to deletemessage from string from list of array

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

how do i do i ask my bot to delete a message send by user based from a list i have.. i tried with the code below but not working :(

Example 1:-

user message : I take orange every morning.

```
var what = ["apple","orange","grape","kiwi","mango","banana"]; 
or
var what = "apple,orange,grape,kiwi,mango,banana";

for (i=0; what.lengt;i++){ ` if(msg.text.toSting().toLowerCase().includes(what[i].toString())) {
        //bot.kickChatMember(msg.chat.id,  msg.from.id);
        bot.deleteMessage(msg.chat.id,  msg.message_id)
    }
```

}

please guide pray

Comment: Help us help you, you should provide more information on the context of your problem, and maybe share some more code, what message are you trying to delete? I'm even pretty sure you can only delete your own message (so the bot's messages).
right now it's hard to understand what might not be working.
Like I said above, try to describe the exact situation/constellation of your app

Comment: This won't sort out the whole thing but there is a typo in the for loop, you need length not lengt: `for (i=0; what.length;i++)`. Can you post the code you're running?